# c# HtmlAgility Pack - Unable to get image src

Tags: c#, html-agility-pack

I am trying to learn how to get all the img src from a URL. But, the `imgs` variable in my code is always `null`. What am I doing wrong?

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();
    doc.LoadHtml("http://archive.ncsa.illinois.edu/primer.html");
    HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlNodeCollection imgs = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//img");

    if (imgs != null)
    {
        foreach (HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlNode img in imgs)
        {
            string imgSrc = img.Attributes["src"].Value;
        }
    }

    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

Comment: Are you sure it is null? You don't do anything with the src attribute. Try printing it: `Console.WriteLine(imgSrc);`.

Comment: Yes, why I am sure it is null is because, when I debug, it does not even come inside the "if (imgs != null)". It skips the line "if (imgs != null)" and goes to Console.ReadKey(); straight away!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using HtmlDocument.LoadHtml which is designed to take html source and not a url.

You could use the WebClient to get the html e.g.

```
WebClient wc = new WebClient();
string html = wc.DownloadString("http://archive.ncsa.illinois.edu/primer.html");
doc.LoadHtml(html);
```

HtmlDocument also supports a Load that allows content to be loaded from various other sources.